# Appium : Cannot run scripts in real device => iOS

Tags: ios, selenium, automation, appium

**Getting below mentioned error :**
The script is running fine on simulators.

> remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred
>   while processing the command. Original error: Could not install app:
>   'Unexpected data:
>   {"Error":"ApplicationVerificationFailed","ErrorDetail":-1,"ErrorDescription":"Failed
>   to verify code signature of
>   /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.hnWgSH/extracted/PentairHome.app
>   : 0xe8008014 (The executable contains an invalid signature.)"}'
>       at getResponseForW3CError (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:804:9)
>       at asyncHandler (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/nod[![m][1]][1]e_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:388:37)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

Comment: are you manually able to install app file and did you built provisioning profile containing udid of device under test ?

Comment: Yes @AmitJain. I am able to install manually.